# Showing a QMessageBox breaks QLineEdit highlighting

Tags: qt, qt4

I have a C++ Qt 4 application written for Raspberry Pi. I'm experiencing an odd side-effect of showing a QMessageBox and I don't know enough about Qt to debug it.

The pi has a touchscreen, so I launch the application with unclutter to hide the mouse cursor. (Though this doesn't affect my issue... I have tried without unclutter just in case.)

I have sub-classed QLineEdit to override focusInEvent() and focusOutEvent() to select-all when a LineEdit gets focus, and deselect-all when it loses focus.

*Before* showing any QMessageBoxes, everything works perfectly - tapping on a QLineEdit selects all the text; tapping the next one de-selects the previous QLineEdit, and selects the new QLineEdit.

*After* showing a QMessageBox, my overridden events stop working, and QLineEdits no longer auto-select and de-select.

If I add:

```
msgBox.setWindowFlags(msgBox.windowFlags() | Qt::Popup);
```

before I exec() the QMessageBox, then text highlighting continues working normally, but the cursor is displayed *and flickers* while the QMessageBox is on the screen.

It seems like there is a side-effect of showing the QMessageBox that affects the calling window and my sub-classed QLineEdit boxes... but not if the QMessageBox has the Popup flag set!

I've tried storing and manually re-loading the flags on the main window, and that does nothing, so it doesn't appear to be flags on the main window.

One more oddity: everything works fine if I run the application remotely over XMing and SSH... it's only when it's run locally on the Pi in plain-old X11 that it freaks out.

Any thoughts on how to debug this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work around this by doing two things.

First, I updated the flags of the QMessageBox before opening it:

```
msgBox.setWindowFlags(Qt::Popup);
msgBox.exec();
```

and second, I hid the cursor in Qt code, rather than relying on Unclutter; this fixed the flickering cursor issue:

```
QApplication::setOverrideCursor(Qt::BlankCursor);
```